# Why can't I get `< and `> to work in MacVim?

Tags: vim, macvim

I have this line in a MacVim buffer:

`abcdefghijklm`

I then type `fev3l<esc>`, to move the cursor to `e`, visually select the text `efgh`, and go back to normal mode.

I then press `` `< `` , and expect the cursor to move to `e`. Instead, it moves to `a`. If I then press `` `> ``, the cursor moves to `h`. Where the cursor actually moves seems a bit arbitrary, but I haven't figured out if there is a consistent pattern.

When doing this in `/usr/bin/vim` on the command line, I get the expected behaviour.

Looking at `:nmap`, I do not have `` ` `` mapped.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: I have a very recent MacVim installed with Homebrew, and it's working as expected in this case. I'm unable to reproduce this.

Comment: I can reproduce on a fresh brew installed MacVim, and also on another machine with a slightly older MacVim. It works in command line vim on both machines.

Comment: did you use --HEAD on installation?

Comment: hah, I was able to reproduce something similar when changing my keyboard layout from `U.S.` to `U.S. International - PC`, which I use for typing in portuguese. In this keyboard layout, accents doesn't come out straight, they need an extra character to get the accent, and that behavior doesn't play nice with MacVim. For me `< goes to the end of the line.

Comment: In OS X when developing I generally stick with US layout to avoid such issues.

Comment: Thanks! I am using a Norwegian keyboard layout. When switching to pure `U.S`, it works both in vim and MacVim. If you change your comment to an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check your keyboard layout.

On a non-US layout that contains diacritics, keys that correspond to diacritic marks will behave differently. Instead of being produced right away, such keys now are meant to be used in combination with another one to produce a letter with a diacritic, which may alter their expected behavior with programs.